# Which disintegration/reveal/build effect is fast for millions of vertices

Tags: rendering, modifiers, geometry-nodes, optimization

I am rendering for disintegration/reveal/build(the built-in modifier) for millions of vertices. I learnt disintegration & reveal effect from popular Youtube tutorial using geometry nodes.

They work very well for simple object with 10k vertices, but I have millions of vertices and I am rendering thousands of frames. It is very slow and it seems all of them use my CPU heavely which is a 11th gen i5.

This is one of geometry node I build.

[image]

My questions

1. Is it possible to move the calculation from CPU to GPU? Would that be faster?
2. Is there anything I can do to reduce CPU time? I changed subdivision limit to 1 for my render.
3. Is there a fast way I can do the same effect with less CPU time?

Comment: Using shader nodes will work at least partly on the GPU. You can make some parts of the mesh transparent without having to update it in memory

Comment: Sounds promising. Could you elaborate more? I am new to blender. I understand what is transparent but I am willing to learn more how does that help. Thanks. @Gorgious